# Modules in ES6 full project

Tags: javascript, class, module, project, ecmascript-6

It's 2016 ES6 is released and Chrome Canary has 93% support for the new ECMA-Script.

So I tried to use Modules in the ES6 way.

Like:

(http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_default-exports-one-per-module)

```
    Or a class:

//------ MyClass.js ------
export default class { ··· } // no semicolon!

//------ main2.js ------
import MyClass from 'MyClass';
const inst = new MyClass();
```

To play around i made an index.html file and two files like above described with some simple content for MyClass like:

```
constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.currentSpeed = 25;
}
```

so i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <module src="MyClass.js"></module>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hallo:)</p>
</body>
</html>
```

in index.html

```
    export default class {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.currentSpeed = 25;
}}
```

in MyClass.js and

```
import MyClass from 'MyClass';
const inst = new MyClass();
```

in main2.js

this isn't working for me. Everytime an error for the import in main2.js.
Is somebody capable to help me?

Comment: The language does not specify **how** modules are loaded. The environment (a.k.a. the browser) has to provide a mechanism, but none does yet. You need additional libraries in order to use modules.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

1. Browsers are not actually shipping ECMAScript module support just yet. I imagine it will be all over Twitter by the time they do.
2. You will need to use `<script type=module src=modulescript.js>` to use module scripts in HTML. (There's also `new Worker("moduleworker.js", {type:"module"})` for workers, but again, not supported just yet.)